# Drawing a "floor" texture

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, let's say that I have a tile texture of some floor or something. And I'd like that my player will walk on that.
How can I set this tile to make it a as a floor? 
I need this tile texture to be all over the screen width right? 
How am I doing it? 
Thanks

Comment: for(int x = 0; x<Area.Width; x+=Texture.Width) { for(int y = 0; y<Area.Height; y+=Texture.Height) { Texture.DrawAt(x, y); } }

Comment: That won't compile by the way, but that's the idea.

Comment: There appears to be a much more supported way of doing it that can be found in two seconds flat by Googling 'xna tiling'. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975153.aspx

Comment: @Thasc, I suggest adding that as an answer, with a bit more detail on the actual usage of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want a really easy way, here it is:
First you create a new Class and name it Tile:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework; // Don't forget those, they will let you
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Content; // access some class like:
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics; // Texture2D or Vector2

namespace Your_Project _Name
{
    class Tile
    {
    }
{
```

So far so good, now create the Texture and Position in your class just like this:

```
namespace Your_Project _Name
{
    class Tile
    {
        Texture2D texture;
        Vector2 position;

        public void Initialize()
        {
        }

        public void Draw()
        {
        }
    }
{
```

As you can see I also created two Methods, Initialize and Draw, now we will Initialize our
texture and position for the tile texture in the public void Initialize(),
I don't know how you use your ContentManager but here is a easy way:

```
public void Initialize(ContentManager Content)
{
    texture = Content.Load<Texture2D>("YourfloorTexture"); //it will load your texture.
    position = new Vector2(); //the position will be (0,0)
}
```

Now we need to draw our texture a number of time how will we do that? The way thasc said, the code can be more complex but here is one that you will understand, I will add a SpriteBatch so I can Draw. All this is done in the public void Draw():

```
public void Draw(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
    {
        for (int i=0; i<30;i++) //will do a loop 30 times. Each Time i will = 
                                //a valor from 0 to 30.
        {
            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, position, Color.White);
            //Will draw the texture once, at the position Vector2 
            //right now position = (0,0)

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2((int)i,(int)i), Color.White);
            //Will Draw the texture 30 times, the first time on the position (0,0)
            //Second Time on (1,1) .. third (2,2) etc...

            spriteBatch.Draw(texture, new Vector2((int)position.X + (i * texture.Width), (int)position.Y + (i * texture.Height), Color.White));
            //Will Draw the Texture 30 times Spaced by the Width and height
            //of the texture (this is the code you need) 
        }

    }
```

I didn't tried it but it should work, now its just a sample, you can figure out the rest. There is a lot of other methods to do it but this one is really easy. Ok, now the final step is to implement this class so go in your principal class where you have all your code and before this:

```
public Game1()
```

Create a new instance of your tile class

```
Tile tile;
```

and Initialize it in the protected override void Initialize():

```
tile = new Tile();
tile.Initialize(Content);
```

Now you have to draw it on the screen go at the end of the class and find protected override void Draw(GameTime gameTime) and call the draw method of our class:

```
spriteBatch.Begin();
tile.Draw(spriteBatch);
spriteBatch.End();
```

This is all the steps to complete a plain simple tile system. As I said there is a lot of others methods you just have to read tutorials about them or create them on your own.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't plan on doing anything extra with the tiled background, I'd recommend thasc's solution and [tile the sprite in a single call](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb975153.aspx).

To do that, you create a rectangle as large as your background, and pass `SamplerState.LinearWrap` to `SpriteBatch.Begin`, then call `Draw` on the background rectangle.

```
Rectangle backgroundRect = new Rectangle(0, 0, backWidth, backHeight);

spriteBatch.Begin(..., ..., SamplerState.LinearWrap, ..., ...);
spriteBatch.Draw(backgroundTexture, backgroundRect, Color.White);
spriteBatch.End();
```

In case you're curious, what this does is create a single polygon that covers the background area, which will grab coordinates off your texture from 0.0f to `backWidth`. Textures are usually mapped between (0.0f, 0.0f) and (1.0f, 1.0f), which represent the corners of the given texture. If you go beyond these boundaries, `TextureAddressMode` defines how these coordinates will be treated:

- `Clamp` will cut down the coordinates back into the 0-1 range.
- `Wrap` will wrap the coordinates back to 0, so 0.0 = 2.0 = 4.0 = etc. and 1.0 = 3.0 = 5.0 = etc.
- `Mirror` will also wrap, but mirroring the texture every other pass, basically going left-to-right-to-left-etc. as the polygon is rendered.